# pandas concat two column into a new one

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file with the following column:

```
timestamp.  message.   name.     DestinationUsername.    sourceUsername
13.05.       hello.     hello.      name1. 
13.05.       hello.     hello.      name2.                  43565
```

what I would like to achieve is to merge together `DestinationUsername` and `SourceUsername` into a new column called `ID`

What I have done so far is the following

```
f=pd.read_csv('file.csv')
f['userID'] = f.destinationUserName + f.sourceUserName
keep_col = ['@timestamp', 'message', 'name', 'destinationUserName', 'sourceUserName', 'userID']

new_f = f[keep_col]
new_f.to_csv("newFile.csv", index=False)
```

But this does not work as expected, because in the output I can see if one of the column `destinationUserName` or `sourceUsername` is empty, than the `userID` is empty, the userId get populated only id `both` destinationUserName and sourceUserName are populated already.

Can anyone help me to understand how I can go over this problem please?

And please if you need more infos just ask me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can typecast the column to string and then remove 'nan' by `replace()` method:

```
df['ID']=(df['DestinationUsername'].astype(str)
          +
          df['sourceUsername'].astype(str).replace('nan','',regex=True))
```

**OR**

```
df['ID']=df[['DestinationUsername','sourceUsername']].astype(str)
                                                     .agg(''.join,1)
                                                     .replace('nan','',regex=True)
```

**Note:** you can also use `apply()` in place of `agg()` method

output of `df['ID']`:

```
0           name1.
1    name2.43565.0
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

### This would help

```
combine=lambda x: '{}{}'.format(x.DestinationUsername,x.sourceUsername)
df['ID'] = df.apply(combine, axis = 1)
df.drop(['DestinationUsername','sourceUsername'],axis=1)
```